# How to map over possibly empty array in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a function whose parameter can either be an empty array or an array with strings.

So I handle this with a union type of  `[] | string[]`

Then, Inside the function, I check to see if the array.length > 0, and if it IS, then I map over the parameter.

```
type Kennel = [] | string[]

const petDogs = (kennel: Kennel)  => {
  if (kennel.length > 0){
    return kennel.map((name:string)=>name)
  } else {
    return "no doggies to pet"
  }
}
```

However, on compilation, I get the error

`Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '(<U>(callbackfn: (value: never, index: number, array: never[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[]) | (<U>(callbackfn: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[])' has no compatible call signatures`

I have tried using function overloading, but it didn't solve the compilation error.

example:

```
interface PetDogs {
  (kennel: []): string;
  (kennel: string[]): string[];
}
```

Comment: Why not just `string[]`?  An empty array is a valid `string[]`.  You don't need to mention the zero-tuple unless you have some other use case.

Comment: This is actually a design flaw in the underlying TypeScript implementation, if you're curious you can [read about it here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29011) but unions with multiple array types always call this error on `Array.map` afaik. jcalz is right, you don't need to use `[] | string[]`, `string[]` is specific enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[]` is a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple), which is meant for a different kind of use case. `string[]` is an array type, and an empty array is still a `string[]` type. Your code would work without compilation errors:

```
type Kennel = string[]

const petDogs = (kennel: Kennel)  => {
  if (kennel.length > 0){
    return kennel.map((name:string)=>name)
  } else {
    return "no doggies to pet"
  }
}

petDogs([]);
petDogs(["Fido", "Doggo"]);
```